# How to define fallback image for get_the_post_thumbnail_url inside a shortcode

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

My shortcode is working fine but how to set a fallback image in there? Please suggestion

```
// display default post as a shortcode with prev/next link

function genericposts_shortcode($atts){
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'expand' => '',
    ), $atts) );
    
    global $paged;
    $posts_per_page = 10;
    $settings = array(
        'showposts' => $posts_per_page, 
        'post_type' => 'post', 
        'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
        'order' => 'ASC', 
        'paged' => $paged
    );
    
    $post_query = new WP_Query( $settings );    
    
    $total_found_posts = $post_query->found_posts;
    $total_page = ceil($total_found_posts / $posts_per_page);
        
    $list = '<div class="bloglist">';
    while($post_query->have_posts()) : $post_query->the_post();
        $list .= '
        <div class="bloglist__item">
            <div class="bloglist__imgwrap">
                <img src=" '. get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full') .'">
            </div>
            <div class="bloglist__wrapt">
                <div class="bloglist__datetitle">
                    <span class="bloglist__date"> '. get_the_date( 'd' ) . '</span>
                    <span class="bloglist__mnt"> '. get_the_date( 'M' ) . '</span>
                    <span class="bloglist__yr"> '. get_the_date( 'Y' ) . '</span>
                    <div class="bloglist__title"> '. get_the_title() .' </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bloglist__more">
                    <a href="'. get_the_permalink() .'" title="'. get_the_title() .'">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        ';        
    endwhile;
    $list.= '</div>';
    
    if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) {
        $list .='<div class="page-navigation">'.wp_pagenavi(array('query' => $post_query, 'echo' => false)).'</div>';
    } else {
        $list.='
        <span class="prev-posts-links">'.get_previous_posts_link('Previous page').'</span>
        <span class="next-posts-links">'.get_next_posts_link('Next page', $total_page).'</span>
        ';
    }
    return $list;
}
add_shortcode('post-shortcode', 'genericposts_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I have solved the issue below way.

add_shortcode( 'post-shortcode', 'genericposts_shortcode' );
function genericposts_shortcode( $atts ) {
    ob_start();
    global $paged;
    $posts_per_page = 9;
    $settings = array(
        'showposts' => $posts_per_page, 
        'post_type' => 'post', 
        'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
        'order' => 'ASC', 
        'paged' => $paged
    );
    
    $post_query = new WP_Query( $settings );    
    
    $total_found_posts = $post_query->found_posts;
    $total_page = ceil($total_found_posts / $posts_per_page);

    if ($post_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
        <div class="bloglist">
            <?php while ( $post_query->have_posts() ) : $post_query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="bloglist__item"  id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                <div class="bloglist__imgwrap">
                    <?php if( !empty(get_the_post_thumbnail()) ) { ?>
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('full');?>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <img src="https://kanooelite.com/upgrade/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/placeholder.png" />
                        <?php } ?>
                </div>
                <div class="bloglist__wrapt">
                    <div class="bloglist__datetitle">
                        <span class="bloglist__date"> <?php echo get_the_date( 'd' ); ?></span>
                        <span class="bloglist__mnt"> <?php echo get_the_date( 'M' ); ?></span>
                        <span class="bloglist__yr"> <?php echo get_the_date( 'Y' ); ?></span>
                        <div class="bloglist__title"> <?php echo get_the_title(); ?></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bloglist__more">
                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div>
        <span class="prev-posts-links"><?php echo get_previous_posts_link('Previous page'); ?></span>
        <span class="next-posts-links"><?php echo get_next_posts_link('Next page', $total_page); ?></span>

    <?php $myvariable = ob_get_clean();
    return $myvariable;
    } ?>
<?php } ?>
```